# Nginx Laravel ignore route

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I'm using laravel in my application. Now I want to install custom
forum software on my domain domain.com/forum.

The problem is that laravel is listening for all incoming routes. What do I have to add to my `nginx` configuration file to make sure it goes to the /forum folder?

Thanks

Comment: You can put your `forum` folder into project's `public` folder.

Comment: @RomanBobrik would not work since the the vhost is configured to send the request to `/public/index.php` of Laravel

Comment: just rechecked on my project. it works. homestead/nginx

Comment: why would nginx be sending **all** requests to Laravel ... it should be setup to check for existing files or folders and serve them before trying to hand off to Laravel otherwise you would never be able to serve a static asset

Answer (score 0):

on the same domain ? that would be difficult.

would be easier to set another domain like `forum.domain.com` with the vhost root folder to be `{your_project_folder}/forum`